# Практикум по ООП

Tags: ооп, python

Так вышло, что в работе никогда не приходилось встречаться с ООП
Терминологию ООП и что как работает - знаю,
но не знаю как это применить в жизни, для чего стоит создавать обьект,
а для чего нет. Хотелось бы какого нибудь "боевого" практикума, а не калькулятора
на классах. Может кто что посоветовать?

Comment: Сделайте шахматы, где каждая фигура это объект, доска это объект и все объектное-ориентированное.

Comment: Что же за работа такая?

     Так вышло, что в работе никогда не приходилось встречаться с ООП

Comment: Администрирование unix. Мелочи на баше, более менее серьезная автоматизация и софт для внутреннего пользования - Python, Perl на работу с текстом

Comment: Ну некоторые, например известный Пол Грэм, и программированием занимались (сейчас он вроде бизнесом занимается -- IT стартапы плодит). Программирование сделало его миллионером.

По свидетельству знатоков, ООП нужен в немаленьком коллективе, чтобы ни один из членов коллектива не смог причинить проекту серьёзный вред.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить в роли практикума  написать что-нибудь маломальски серьезное с использованием библиотеки PyQt4.

Answer (score 3):

В учебном курсе http://www.specialist.ru/course/python2 рассматривается хороший пример программы для бухучета. Сам курс можно найти в нете.